# How to prevent duplicate instantiation of Objects (by its unique ID) in Swift?

Tags: swift

My program manages Task objects.
Each Task object has a unique "taskID".

The class is:

```
class Task: Codable, Equatable {
    var taskID: Int64
    // ... plus other variables

    static func == (left: Task, right: Task) -> Bool {
        return left.taskID == right.taskID
    }
}
```

Upon successful RESTful calls, Task objects are instantiated by the JSONDecoder as in:

> try JSONDecoder().decode([Task].self, from: jsonData!)

... and placed into **different** arrays and dictionaries.

Different parts of the program will call different RESTful methods and retrieve the same Task objects (I define Tasks objects are the **same** with the *same* "taskID"). The PROBLEM is the code has no knowledge of other same Task object in existence being stored in different arrays or dictionaries.

**Solution Needed:**

I need to implement it so there is only 1 Task object for each unique "taskID". That means there cannot be more than 1 copy of the same Task with the same "taskID"

(It is not a singleton because there are many unique Task objects.)

To explain this clearer:
My program using RESTful methods to retrieve data which is returned in JSON format. There should be only 1 copy per object (ie. Task) identified by its "taskID" stored in the entire program. If a Task object has already been created previously, it should not be re-created. All arrays and dictionary should point the same Task objects.

What is the easiest solution to implement this? (I'm thinking of some methods to override the init() method ...) How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a `TaskFactory` class, that stores a `[TaskID: Task]`, and has a `func getTask(withID: Int64) -> Task` method, that either returns `self.tasks[id, default: Task(...)]`

Comment: How do I use this TaskFactory class with the JSONDecoder() ?

Comment: MMmmm, good question. One annoying way is to override `init(decoder:)` for every decodable type that has a `Task` member, and do the check manually there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I have created this type of extension when comparison is possible before creating the same objects.

You have multiple objects of `Task` so we will create an extension of `Array` iterating through the created tasks objects and compare using their `taskID`.

```
extension Array where Element: Task {
    internal static func decode(_ json: Data) throws -> [Task] {
        let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        var arrTasks: [Task] = []
        if let jsonObject = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: [])) as? Array<Any> {
            for json in jsonObject {
                if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: []), let task = (try? jsonDecoder.decode(Task.self, from: data)) {
                    if !arrTasks.contains(task) {
                        arrTasks.append(task)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arrTasks
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
if let tasks = try? [Task].decode(data) {
    //Other Stuffs...
}
```

Let me know this helps or not!

Comment: Why do you de-serialize the json, only to re-serialize it again?

Comment: Yes or else `JSONDecoder` will be of no use! Any other way you can think of?

Comment: I'll sleep on it. Perhaps an interning pattern might work. https://pastebin.com/KHz8LWs1

Comment: Ummm...nicer way, in this I think `TaskRepository` will be an `Array` of attaching each `Task` and later on you will be comparing with it, right?

Comment: Why would you use an array? You want fast look-up by id, a dict is more suitable

Comment: This code worked for me. However, I had to modify it to suit my needs. Instead of instantiating the arrTasks within the method, I had to pass an inout parameter into the function. In addition, I changed to a static function instead of an extension of Array. Thanks!